# Appcelerator Bouncy Keyboard Toolbar Bug

Tags: ios, keyboard, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Appcelerator Bouncy Keyboard Toolbar Bug

Hi all i am trying to find a fix for a bouncy keyboard toolbar with Appcelerator here is a video of the issue which i cannot find a fix look on various forums there was a animate set to false fix which didnt seem to work.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cd95W1LvNXk&feature=youtu.be

```
$.pinOne.keyboardToolbar = Titanium.UI.iOS.createToolbar({
            barColor : Alloy.Globals.Device.grey,
            tintColor : "#FFF",
            items : [cancelOne, Titanium.UI.createButton({
                systemButton : Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.FLEXIBLE_SPACE
            }), doneOne]
        });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's hard to see because you didn't enable slow animations when you record the video, but it does seem like a possible bug if indeed that iOS Dev (I assume you mean someone who codes in Xcode) doesn't have this issue. Please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: Watch it at 0.25 speed and you'll see the issue

Answer (score 0):

Watched the video three times and I'm still not sure what you are expecting or trying to fix. Not sure what you mean by bouncy... Maybe you could give a better description of what exactly you're trying to fix.

Comment: Well is the keyboard toolbar suppose to animate quicker than the number pad so you end up with a bounce effect it does not stick to top of the number pad there is a gap the iOS Dev in our office doesn't have the same issue no bounce they open up without any gap?

Comment: Sorry, not sure at all on that one.

Comment: Watch it at 0.25 speed